# constracting a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(z_k)$ be a sequence od distinct points in a domain $G$ that accumulates to $\partial G$, and and let $(w_k)\subset \mathbb{C}$.
Show that there exists $f\in Hol(G)$ such that $f(z_k)=w_k$ for all $k$.

it needs to be related Runge's theorem but I can't see how.

Comment: What's relation between $w_k$'s? Suppose $z_k=\frac{1}{k}$ and $w_k\in\mathbb Q$, Is there such holomorphic map?

Comment: @Maryam: sure. If, for instance, $w_k=k$, then $f(z)=1/z$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$ with $f(z_k)=w_k$.

Comment: @Maryam: I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean. Of course there always is such a holomorphic map $f$,  and that $w_k\in \mathbb Q$ is completely irrelevant.

Comment: This is not trivial. If I recall correctly it follows from the Mittag-Leffler theorem - see for example Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_.